# Pandas merge with average of second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two panda dataframes.

Data frame one has three columns:

| name | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alice | 04:00 | 05:00 |
| bob | 05:00 | 07:00 |

Data frame two has three columns:

| time | points_1 | points_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04:30 | 5 | 4 |
| 04:45 | 8 | 6 |
| 05:30 | 10 | 3 |
| 06:15 | 4 | 7 |
| 06:55 | 1 | 0 |

I would like to merge the two dataframes such that the first dataframe now has 5 columns:

| name | start_time | end_time | average_point_1 | average_point_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alice | 04:00 | 05:00 | 6.5 | 5 |
| bob | 05:00 | 07:00 | 5 | 3.33 |

Where the average_point_1 columns consists of average of points_1 from dataframe two between the start and end time for each row. Similarly average_point_2. Could someone tell me how I can merge the two dataframes like this without having to develop an averaging function to make the columns first and then merging.

Comment: Provide samples of your data and your expected output.

Comment: Does your dataframe 2 provide names ?

Comment: no dataframe 2 does not provide names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#convert all time fields to datetime for merge_asof compatibility
df1["start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["start_time"],format="%H:%M")
df1["end_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["end_time"],format="%H:%M")
df2["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["time"],format="%H:%M")

#merge both dataframes on time
merged = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, left_on="time", right_on="start_time")

#groupy and get average for each name
output = merged.groupby(["name", "start_time", "end_time"],as_index=False).mean()

#convert time columns back to strings if needed
output["start_time"] = output["start_time"].dt.strftime("%H:%M")
output["end_time"] = output["end_time"].dt.strftime("%H:%M")

>>> output
     name start_time end_time  points_1  points_2
0  alice      04:00    05:00       6.5  5.000000
1    bob      05:00    07:00       5.0  3.333333
```

Comment: for the function merge_asof wouldn't it be better to use merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on="start_time", right_on="time", direction='forward')?

Comment: @user142756 - No, `merge_asof` only allows left join so you need `df2` to be the left DataFrame